# Android & TabHost - Detect change state?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am using TabHosts on android I need to detect changes even if the tapped item is the current item?
How can i achieve this?

The following gets called only the selected item has changed.
I want to manually do something like:

```
 tab.setCurrentTabByTag("Item1");
```

to call the setOnTabChangedListener.

```
 tab.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

            }});
```

Comment: I'd like to know this as well.